# Google Calendar API - list all timezones

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

Is there any way to see all possible timezones used by the Google Calendar API?

I've run into the issue of having to map Google's timezones with PHP timezone.  For example, Google Calendar could have `US/Eastern` which could be mapped to `America/New_York` by my app.

Note: I'm looking for all timezone **outputs** by Google (as opposed to **allowable inputs** as per this question: [List of acceptable Google Calendar api time zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526635/list-of-acceptable-google-calendar-api-time-zones))

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526635/list-of-acceptable-google-calendar-api-time-zones

Answer (score 0):

Timezones use the IANA Time Zone Database names (http://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Comment: Thanks but maybe I'm getting something wrong... The IANA tz database doesn't seem to include US/Eastern, for example, which Google Calendar uses